# programming standalone 64 bit processor in x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit

I am learning about the x64 and x86 architecture and assembly language commands but i was wondering how i actually burn a program i create onto the standalone processor.  Like with avrs the mcu is standalone and you buy a programmer and you can practically create your own cell phone by hooking up lcds and gsm modules up to the input and output pins.  with the avr you hook up the programmer to your computers usb port then once the program is burned the mcu runs without being connected to the computer and screen.  My question is how do i program a x64 bit processor outside of a computer so i can hook up my own lcds or electronics modules to it.  PLease help me cause everything i have read is using x64 bit assembly on a actual computer.  also is there like an x64 breakout board.

Comment: A typical x64 processor comes on a chip with about a 1000 pins.  They need a chipset to implement the I/O and memory busses.  You'll have a very hard time finding a breakout board for it.  They were simply not designed for embedded applications.

Comment: Newer chips have the northbridge in-package with the CPU.  So you just need a southbridge as an external part (plus some other support stuff - RAM for example).  There are plenty of single board computers that could be considered "x64 breakout boards", though.

Comment: @carl norum  I think you are right on the money with what i am trying to learn and accomplish.  Do you have any examples of what i could accomplish with a single board computer or how to implement input output to my own peripherals (lcds, ect) with a southbridge.  Would i be incorrect in saying that a motherboard is kinda like a single board computer.  How would i start coding in assembly for one of these single board computers and how much would they cost.

Answer (score 1):

Your experience with embedded CPUs has led you astray. What you're trying to do is not going to work.

1. x86 CPUs are not available in "breakout boards". There's simply way too much support hardware they need to run. The closest you're going to get is a standard computer motherboard.
2. Unlike the embedded CPUs you've probably worked with, x86 CPUs do not have onboard flash - they typically boot from a onboard flash chip (the BIOS chip) which in turn loads a program (the OS) from a hard drive or other storage device. The BIOS is extremely system-specific, and is best considered non-user-modifiable.
3. x86 systems do not typically have very many easily usable I/Os. Most of the available busses tend to be in forms that are hard to work with, like PCIe or stranger things.

If you want to develop for x86, develop for a computer, not for a standalone x86 system (which doesn't really exist). If you want to develop for an embedded system, pick something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the specific documentation for your processor from Intel, but the basic idea is that the chip comes up in 16-bit real mode and starts executing code from a magic address.  Normally, you hook up an EEPROM device of some kind to the processor in some way to put the code at that magic address.

The 16-bit real mode assembly code you write and put in that ROM can then change the processor mode to 32-bit and 64-bit mode as you'd like.  You'll need to do RAM initialization along the way, too.  From my time working on boot ROM for Intel machines, I seem recall that Intel preferred to keep their memory initialization code secret.  Maybe the documentation you find will help you get all that stuff set up, or otherwise you'll need to talk to a sales/application engineer at Intel to get going.